# Loop user input with if statements in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I was wondering if someone here could help better explain For loops than my textbooks.

I'm writing a program in Python where the program askes a user if they're already an existing user. If they are an existing user, the program starts. If they're not an existing user, they're prompted to create a username and password.

I was wondering if someone could help explain how I could use a For Loop to loop the if statement incase a user enters some unexpected input like A or a number.

Thanks

Here's a code snippet of an if statement I have where it goes:

```
if newuser == "y":
    print("Hello New User")
elif newuser == "n":
    print("Hello Existing User")
else:
    print("Please try again")
```

Comment: You want a `while` loop for this, not a `for` loop.  A `for` loop steps a variable through an iterable, which doesn't apply to your situation since there is no iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a while loop, and only break out of this if a condition is met.

```
while True:
    newuser = input('enter y/n')
    if newuser == "y":
        print("Hello New User")
        break
    elif newuser == "n":
        print("Hello Existing User")
        break
    else:
        print("Please try again")
```